# how to change fillter color file svg in css

Tags: html, css

I include CSS in HTML and I used it before,

I try to use a filler color but this not working.

```css
.list-dots-menu-right::before {
  content : url("../image/svg/dots-six-vertical.svg");
  display : contents;
  filter  : invert(0%) sepia(0%) saturate(21%) hue-rotate(38deg) brightness(60%) contrast(105%);
  }
```

Comment: unlikely to work, css properties of svg elements are different from properties of html elements. you also have to take into account SVG content structuring

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The [content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) property does not work in that way.

To apply the filter, you would want to simply put the [SVG element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/svg) in the html, and assign CSS properties on it, the following is an example:

HTML:

```html
<html>
  <!-- ... -->
  <svg class="my-svg">
    <!-- svg content -->
  </svg>
  <!-- ... -->
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
.my-svg {
  filter: invert(0%) sepia(0%) saturate(21%) hue-rotate(38deg) brightness(60%)
    contrast(105%);
}
```